# 'NoneType' object is not iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, list-comprehension

```
def merge_list(list1,list2):

    res_list=[]
    list2=list2.reverse()
    conv = lambda i : i or '' 
    res = [conv(i) for i in list2] 
    for i in range(0,len(list1)):
        res_list.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
        merged_data=' '.join(res_list)
    return merged_data
list1 = ['A', 'app', 'a', 'd','ke','th','doc','awa']
list2=['y','tor','e','eps','ay',None,'le','n']
data=merge_list(list1,list2)
data
```

I'm trying to reverse `list2` and concatenate the strings from both the lists to get a string as result. The objective is to ignore `None` in the list if there is any, and print the final sentence.

Comment: What do you mean by ignore the None?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is that you have used

```
list2=list2.reverse()
```

the `list.reverse()` method reverses the list in place, the method itself returns `None`. To fix this, change the line to just read:

```
list2.reverse()
```

Also, you have used

```
res_list.append(list1[i]+list2[i])
```

This should probably read

```
res_list.append(list1[i]+res[i])
```

These corrections give the output:

```
'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'
```

Another way to solve this problem is as a one-liner, using `zip`, list slicing to reverse `list2`, and ternary statements to apply the `None -> ''` logic.

```
>>> list1 = ['A', 'app', 'a', 'd', 'ke', 'th', 'doc', 'awa']
>>> list2 = ['y', 'tor', 'e', 'eps', 'ay', None, 'le', 'n']
>>> ' '.join(''.join(y if y else '' for y in x) for x in zip(list1, list2[::-1]))
'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Replace `None` in both the lists:

```
>>> list1 = [x if x else "" for x in list1]
>>> list2 = [x if x else "" for x in list2]
```

2) zip and iterate:

```
>>> lis=[]
>>> for x,y in zip(list1,list2[::-1]):
...     lis.append(x+y)
```

3) join:

```
>>> " ".join(lis)
'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'
```

CDJB's one liner combines all these steps